# Sshd error : Decryption integrity check failed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, openssh

I can't connect to linux machine over ssh:
The server logs (Sshd) :

```
Connection from 192.168.1.102 port 51947 on 192.168.1.100 port 2222
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 996/993 [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
Decryption integrity check failed [preauth]
debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: Killing privsep child 5824
```

UPD
this solution solve the problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44562088/connection-closed-by-remote-host-in-ssh-while-in-putty-all-goes-well

Comment: That's basically the server's way of saying "incorrect password". That doesn't look like a complete log, it's missing timestamps, process names etc. - could you please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1679887/edit) your question to add that? Could you please also add output of `ssh user@system -v`?

Comment: If you've resolved your issue, please feel free to [answer it](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) as well, and check back in 48 hours to accept it so it's useful for others later down the line. Please note that a link-only answer is very likely to get flagged as low quality, so I'd advise checking [how to write a good answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) to prevent that. Alternatively you can of course delete the question.